# Finding the Largest Partition of Non-Connected Nodes in a Graph in polynomial time

Tags: performance, math, graph, computer-science, graph-theory

I have a graph, and I want to determine the largest possible set (or partition) of nodes such that no two nodes within this set have an edge between them. I am looking for an efficient algorithm to solve this problem.

For instance, given the following graph:

```
1: [2]
2: [1, 3, 5, 6, 4]
3: [2, 4]
4: [3, 5, 6, 2]
5: [4, 2]
6: [4, 2]
```

The largest partition of non-connected nodes would be {1, 3, 5, 6}.

My current approach is brute-force: I generate all combinations of nodes and then verify if any of the nodes within a combination share an edge. This method, however, is not efficient for larger graphs.

Graphically, I intuitively group unconnected nodes together, and as I add nodes to this group, I can easily identify the largest possible set of non-connected nodes. Is there a way to replicate this intuition algorithmically?

Comment: By 'I generate all combinations of nodes' do you mean you test 2^n combinations? If so, I think it shouldn't be hard to improve on that.

Comment: This is a well-studied topic. The search term you want is either "maximum independent set" or "maximum clique" (the latter applied to the complement of the graph). Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory) (skip down to 'finding independent sets', and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem

Answer (score 1):

- SET G to input graph
- Create A an empty set of nodes
- LOOP S over nodes in G

  - Create W an empty graph
  - Move S from G to W
  - LOOP S2 over nodes in G

    - IF S2 has no link to any node in W

      - Move S2 from G to W
    - ENDLOOP S2
  - IF node count of W > size of A

    - Set A to all the nodes in W
  - reset G to input graph
  - ENDLOOP S
- Output A

Comment: Are you sure this guarantees the largest possible set?

Comment: This will find a maximal independent set, but is not guaranteed to find the maximum independent set. E.g., say we have n vertices, vertex 0 has no neighbors, vertex 1 has every neighbor but 0, and no other edges exist, and assume we process vertices in this order. Then the maximum independent set is {0,2,3,...,n} but this will bucket 0 with 1, miss the maximal independent sent, and eventually return {2,3,...,n}.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try to invert graph, making edges where there are not present, and removing edges where are present now. Thus, your problem would be equivalent to finding largest connected component of the inverted graph.

Finding largest connected component of the graph is a known problem. DFS could be used or finding null space of the graph Laplacian might work as well.

Comment: This inversion method is definitely a clever approach which I am currently looking into. However, this alone would not work since the largest connected component would need to be fully connected in order for it to be a partition. I will look into the other methods though as well.

Comment: This is wrong. The OP is asking for the largest possible set of nodes such that no two nodes within this set have an edge between them. If the analogous structure in the complement of the graph (inverse in your terms) would be a clique, not simply a connected component: a set of nodes where every edge is present.

Comment: @Dave Yes, original author already said this, and 
sadly I agree - not enough to get it working